# How to connect mysql Database with Dart?

Tags: mysql, database, dart

Does anyone can tell me how to connect to mysql database with Dart? I've been reading and searching for days but can't find any suitable answers. I just learning web programming. Thank you!

Comment: This problem I've solved recently. I just created a server with NodeJS, then I connect my flutter app yo mysql through a rest API.

Answer (score 15):

You can use [SQLJocky](http://pub.dartlang.org/packages/sqljocky) to connect to MySQL. Add

```
dependencies:
  sqljocky: 0.0.4
```

to your **pubspec.yaml** an run **pub install**. Now you can connect to MySQL like this

```
var cnx = new Connection();
cnx.connect(username, password, dbName, port, hostname).then((nothing) {
    // Do something with the connection
    cnx.query("show tables").then((Results results) {
    print("tables");
    for (List row in results) {
      print(row);
    }
  });
});
```

Answer (score 9):

I think for dart 2 [`mysql1`](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/mysql1) is a simple choice.

Example:

```
import 'package:mysql1/mysql1.dart';

Future main() async {
  // Open a connection (testdb should already exist)
  final connection = await MySqlConnection.connect(new ConnectionSettings(
      host: '10.0.2.2',
      port: 3306,
      user: 'root',
      password: '0123456789',
      db: 'development',
      ));
  var results = await connection.query('select * from tableName');
  for (var row in results) {
    print('${row[0]}');
  }

  // Finally, close the connection
  await connection.close();
}
```

(tested on Dart version 2.1.0 (build 2.1.0-dev.9.4 f9ebf21297))

Comment: how to connect with SSH?

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tried this, but here is one: [http://github.com/jamesots/sqljocky](https://github.com/jamesots/sqljocky)

Answer (score 0):

You can try using sqljocky -> http://pub.dartlang.org/packages/sqljocky

Comment: Mine is giving me late initialization error have you tackle with this error, when you connect to MySQL connection it gives you late initialization or null error