# mysql connection using dart program

Tags: mysql, dart

import 'package:sqljocky/sqljocky.dart';
import 'dart:async';
var pool = new ConnectionPool(host: 'localhost', port: 3306, user: 'bob', password: 'wibble', db: 'stuff', max: 5);

Comment: What is this? I cant understand anything...

Comment: Can we connect mysql db using dart program?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11963444/how-to-connect-mysql-database-with-dart