# Connecting to a mySQL database on dart 2

Tags: mysql, dart, dart-2

I was looking for a way to connect to a mysql database  using dart.

I found the same question: [How to connect mysql Database with Dart?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11963444/how-to-connect-mysql-database-with-dart)

unfortunately, sqljocky is not dart 2 compatible, so my question is whether there exists a replacement that is dart 2 compatible.

EDIT: as Alex Jone pointed out, [mysql1](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/mysql1) is working.

Comment: Dart Web Platform does not intended for such use. There are no guarantees for this. There is also no official support and it is does not planned. So this is a very risky attempt in order to use Dart in such a way.

Comment: check the most recent answer in the question you provided