# How create a persistentStore to MySQL with Aqueduct?

Tags: rest, dart, aqueduct

I'm trying to create a context with dataModel and persistentStore... Follow the code below working with PostgreSQL:

```
  @override
  Future prepare() async {
    logger.onRecord.listen((rec) => print("$rec ${rec.error ?? ""} ${rec.stackTrace ?? ""}"));

    final dataModel = ManagedDataModel.fromCurrentMirrorSystem();
    final persistentStore = PostgreSQLPersistentStore.fromConnectionInfo(
      "heroes_user", "password", "localhost", 5432, "heroes");

    context = ManagedContext(dataModel, persistentStore);
  }
```

I want use MySQL instead PostgreSQL, I dont find any tutorial using it.

Comment: Why do you want to use MySQL instead of PostgreSQL?

Comment: I don't think it is necessary to use MySQL, but I am curios from a theoretical perspective how to add a different database.

Comment: Cause I just have experience with MySQL, and my time is short to learn PostgreSQL! :/

Comment: I would expect you could use one of [these pub packages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11963444/how-to-connect-mysql-database-with-dart). It won't have the ORM that Aqueduct provides for PostgreSQL, though.

Comment: [PostgreSQL vs MySQL](https://www.2ndquadrant.com/en/postgresql/postgresql-vs-mysql/)

Comment: Thanks for the support dude, but u know if I can use sqljocky with aqueduct? (I'm using sqljocky as an example, but I'm talking about other kinda of packes) Can I create a connection and from it create the dataModel I need?

Comment: You can use other packages along with Aqueduct. I've done that before. I haven't used an alternate database, but I don't expect the package itself to be a problem. The part I don't know is how to create a [service](http://aqueduct.io/docs/core_concepts/#services) for it.

Comment: I have a persistentStore which get the connection object to create my ManagedContext. If I use these packages to create my connection, I can use it to create that persistentStore without any ploblem?

Comment: I'm not sure. While waiting for someone who knows to answer, try it out and update your question with more details as you learn more. If your solve it yourself, all the better. You can add your own answer to help me and other people with the same question.

Comment: You can use [mysql1](https://pub.dev/packages/mysql1) package to connect to MySQL

I haven't tried it myself but the library looks well maintained

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is the general procedure using another type of database:

- Find a MySQL Dart package. (maybe [this one](https://pub.dev/packages/mysql1))
- Create a class that extends Aqueduct's [`PersistentStore`](https://github.com/stablekernel/aqueduct/blob/master/aqueduct/lib/src/db/persistent_store/persistent_store.dart).
- Implement the abstract methods for MySQL. (For reference, see how [`PostgreSQLPersistentStore`](https://github.com/stablekernel/aqueduct/blob/15968dea3c144684d4bc5ea55a3c9e323199837c/aqueduct/lib/src/db/postgresql/postgresql_persistent_store.dart) does it in PostgreSQL.)
- If you are using authentication, do the same for [`AuthServerDelegate`](https://github.com/stablekernel/aqueduct/blob/master/aqueduct/lib/src/auth/protocols.dart). (For reference, see how [`ManagedAuthDelegate`](https://github.com/stablekernel/aqueduct/blob/master/aqueduct/lib/managed_auth.dart) does it in PostgreSQL.)
- Create lots of tests to check your work.

My recommendation:

- Use the default PostgreSQL implementation. It will take a lot less time to learn than it will to implement everything on your own for MySQL. The default implementation is probably also better tested. With the ORM, you don't even use much raw PostgreSQL code anyway, which itself isn't significantly different than raw MySQL code.
- You could also check out the [Angel](https://github.com/angel-dart/angel) server, which seems to be more modular than Aqueduct, but you are still going to have to implement your own MySQL service. See [this](https://github.com/angel-dart/angel/issues/36).
- Do as much development as you can without choosing a framework or database. As a principle of clean architecture, these are details. If possible, abstract them away. See [Clean architecture for the rest of us](https://pusher.com/tutorials/clean-architecture-introduction).